# AJAX form not triggering POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting my hand at ajax which i'm not the greatest at, my code for the page:

```
<?php
include('includes/db_connection.php');
include('includes/sessions.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/navbar-logged.php');
require_once('api-sape.php');
// init sape
$sape        = new SapeApi();
$userId      = $sape->login(SAPE_USER, SAPE_PASS);  

?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modal-loading {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 999;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            display: none;
        }

        .modal-loading .loading {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            margin: 200px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <div class="modal-loading"><div class="loading"><img src="http://wz.sera5902.myjino.ru/loading.gif"></div></div>
<?php
// isset
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // show var_dump
    if ($member == SAPE_USER) { showPre($_POST); }
    // try...
    try 
    {
        // vars
        $sapeURLID       = $_POST['url_id'];  
        $sapeDepth       = $_POST['domain_level'];
        $sapeInInG       = $_POST['indexed_in_google'];
        $sapeOrder       = $_POST['order'];
        $sapePLeve       = $_POST['page_level'];
        $sapeSdays       = $_POST['search_days'];
        $sapeKwdos       = $_POST['keyword'];
        $sapeKwpla       = $_POST['keyword_placement'];
        $sapeSdmoz       = $_POST['site_in_dmoz'];
        $sapeExtLi       = $_POST['external_links'];
        $sapePriFr       = $_POST['price_from'];
        $sapePriTo       = $_POST['price_to'];
        $sapeMajC1       = $_POST['mj_cf_1'];
        $sapeMajC2       = $_POST['mj_cf_2'];
        $sapeMajT1       = $_POST['mj_tf_1'];
        $sapeMajT2       = $_POST['mj_tf_2'];
        $sapePageN       = $_POST['page_number'];
        // arrays
        $zones = array();
        if (isset($_POST['zones'])) {
            if (count($_POST['zones']) > 0) {
                foreach ($_POST['zones'] as $key => $value) {
                  $zones[] = $value;
                }           
            }           
        }
        // arrays
        $cats = array();
        if (isset($_POST['categories'])) {
            if (count($_POST['categories']) > 0) {
                foreach ($_POST['categories'] as $key => $value) {
                  $cats[] = $value;
                }           
            }
        }
        // xml-rpc query
        $userSearch      = $sape->search($sapeURLID, array("order"=>$sapeOrder,"domain_level"=>$sapeDepth,"domain_zones"=>$zones,"categories"=>$cats,"flag_blocked_in_google"=>$sapeInInG,"level_from"=>$sapePLeve,"days_old_whois"=>$sapeSdays,"words"=>str_replace(" ", "+", $sapeKwdos),"words_type"=>$sapeKwpla,"in_dmoz"=>$sapeSdmoz,"ext_links"=>$sapeExtLi,"pr_from"=>$sapePriFr,"pr_2"=>$sapePriTo,"mj_cf_1"=>$sapeMajC1,"mj_cf_2"=>$sapeMajC2,"mj_tf_1"=>$sapeMajT1,"mj_tf_2"=>$sapeMajT2), $sapePageN);   
        // is there any results?
        if (count($userSearch) == 0) {
            stderr("No results with those filters, try again with more options selected.");
        }       
        // loop results
        foreach ($userSearch as $val1) {
                // ignore blank urls
                if (!empty($val1['url'])) { 
                    if ($member == SAPE_USER) { 
                        echo "<pre>";
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<b>ID:</b> " . $val1['id'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<b>URL:</b> " . $val1['url'];
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<br />";  
                    }   
                    foreach ($val1['pages'] as $key => $val2) {
                        $urlCheck = DB::getInstance()->selectOne(
                            '
                            SELECT  DISTINCT site_sape_url, site_uri
                            FROM    `sites`
                            WHERE   `site_sape_url` = :site_sape_url
                            AND     `site_uri` = :site_uri',
                            [
                                'site_sape_url' => $val1['url'],
                                'site_uri' => $val2['uri']
                            ]
                        );
                        // count check
                        if (!count($urlCheck)) {
                            // ten op for the site level
                            $level = ($val2['uri'] == "/") ? '1' : $val2['level'];  
                            // get site ip
                            $ip = gethostbyname(parse_url($val1['url'], PHP_URL_HOST));                     
                            // insertion
                            DB::getInstance()->insert(
                                'sites',
                            [
                                'site_sape_id' => $val1['id'],
                                'site_sape_url' => $val1['url'],
                                'site_uri_id' => $val2['id'],
                                'site_uri' => $val2['uri'],
                                'site_uri_price' => $val2['price'],
                                'site_level' => $level,
                                'site_pages_in_google' => $val1['nof_pages_in_google'],
                                'site_ip' => $ip,
                                'site_added' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                            ]);                                                     
                        }                               
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        // have we already checked the link stats?
/*                      $already = DB::getInstance()->select("SELECT * FROM `metrics` WHERE `metrics_url`='".trim($val1['url'] . $val2['uri'])."'");
                        if (!count($already)) {
                            // vars
                            $fURL = returnDomDetails(trim($val1['url'] . $val2['uri']));            
                            // domdetailer  
                            $domMajestic = json_decode($fURL);  
                            if ($domMajestic) {
                                    // avoid "PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object" warnings
                                    DB::getInstance()->insert(
                                    'metrics',
                                    [
                                    'metrics_user_id' => 1,
                                    'metrics_url' => $metricsURL,
                                    'metrics_moz_links' => $domMajestic->mozLinks,
                                    'metrics_mozPA' => $domMajestic->mozPA,
                                    'metrics_mozDA' => $domMajestic->mozDA,
                                    'metrics_mozRank' => $domMajestic->mozRank,
                                    'metrics_mozTrust' => $domMajestic->mozTrust,
                                    'metrics_FB_comments' => $domMajestic->FB_comments,
                                    'metrics_FB_shares' => $domMajestic->FB_shares,
                                    'metrics_google_plus_one' => $domMajestic->google_plus_one,
                                    'metrics_pinterest_pins' => $domMajestic->pinterest_pins,
                                    'metrics_linkedin' => $domMajestic->linkedin,
                                    'metrics_majesticLinks' => $domMajestic->majesticLinks,
                                    'metrics_majesticRefDomains' => $domMajestic->majesticRefDomains,
                                    'metrics_majesticCF' => $domMajestic->majesticCF,
                                    'metrics_majesticTF' => $domMajestic->majesticTF,
                                    'metrics_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                    ]); 
                            }   
                        } */    
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                        
                        if ($member == SAPE_USER) { 
                            echo "<br />";
                            echo "<b>------------->Page ID:</b> " . $val2['id'];
                            echo "<br />";
                            echo "<b>------------->Page:</b> " . $val2['uri'];
                            echo "<br />";
                            echo "<br />";  
                        }
                    } 
                    if ($member == SAPE_USER) { 
                            echo "</pre>";
                    }
                }
        } 
        // show var_dump
        if ($member == SAPE_USER) { showPre($userSearch); }
        // message
        stdmsg('Search complete, view the results <a href="buy-links.php">here</a>.');
    } catch (SapeApiException $e) {
            if ($e->getMessage() == "SAPE.RU: Search result is too big :o(") {
                stderr('Your search query has too many results, try refining your search options to be more specific.');
            } else {
                stderr($e->getMessage());
            }
    }
}
// get the logged in users id
$row = get_logged_in_users_details($member);
// the ID
$hID = $row['member_id'];
?>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Search - To get a Link ID you need to create a project.</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form id="search-form" action="search.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal container-fluid" role="form">

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtLinkID" class="control-label">Link ID:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select id="txtLinkID" name="url_id" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $rows = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `project_member_id`='.$hID);   
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['project_sape_link_id']) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['project_sape_link_id']) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtLevelDepth" class="control-label">Domain Level:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="txtLevelDepth" name="domain_level" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $level = array(0 => "1",1 => "2",2 => "3");
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($level as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtLevelDepth" class="control-label">Nesting Pages:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="txtLevelDepth" name="page_level" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $nesting = array(0 => "page_level_1",1 => "page_level_2",2 => "page_level_3");
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($nesting as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Categories:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?php
                            $rows = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `categories`');   
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['cat_sape_id']) ?>"> - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']) ?><br>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Zones:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?php
                            $rows = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `zones`');   
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="zones[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['zone_sape_id']) ?>"> - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['zone_name']) ?><br>
                            <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Indexed in Google:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="" name="indexed_in_google" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $depth = array(0 => "Yes",1 => "No",2 => "Does not matter");
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($depth as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Site in DMOZ:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="" name="site_in_dmoz" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $dmoz = array(1 => "No", 0 => "Yes");
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($dmoz as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">Site Must Be older Than (in days):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="search_days" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">Site Must Contain This Keyword:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="keyword" value="" class="form-control" size="40" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">Keyword Should Be:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="" name="keyword_placement" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $depth = array(0 => "On the page somewhere",1 => "In the <title>Keyword(s)</title> tags");
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($depth as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">No More Than This Number of External Links On-Page:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="external_links" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">Price (From):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="price_from" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">Price (To):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="price_to" value="500" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="txtCR" class="control-label">Majestic CF (Min):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="mj_cf_1" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">Majestic CF (Max):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="mj_cf_2" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">Majestic TF (Min):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="mj_tf_1" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">Majestic TF (Max):</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" id="" name="mj_tf_2" value="0" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Order Results By:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="" name="order" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php
                            $depth = array(9 => "Lowest price first",19 => "Highest price first",4 => "Category Descending",14 => "Category Ascending");
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($depth as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label"># Of Pages Of Results:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select id="" name="page_number" class="form-control" required="required">
                            <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $x ?>"><?php echo $x ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label" style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenID" value="<?php echo $hID; ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Search for links using <b>your</b> criteria.</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search-form').submit(function(){
            $('.modal-loading').fadeIn();
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(html){
                $('.modal-loading').fadeOut();
                var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                newDoc.write(html);
                newDoc.close();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php

include('includes/footer.php');
```

Once the "search" is pressed, i wanted a loading .gif to appear to show the user it's working (this shows fine) the problem is, the form doesn't seem to be submitting, the **if (isset($_POST['search'])) {** is not being triggered for some reason, can anyone see anything i have missed?

Answer (score 0):

This is the major problem with W3Schools and people following it.

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
```

Will never be sent! Or triggered. You need to check the Network Tab for what all is going to the POST request.

You need to check with:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
```

Or something that you are sending.